# Server.Transfer for Button Click in Gridview will not transfer to designated page.

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I need help with figuring out why the buttons in a Gridview are not transferring to the designated pages when clicked.

I added a button (Button1) outside of the GridView, for which the Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx") will work, yet it won't work for the buttons in the GridView (it just renders a postback to the same page).
Does anyone know why the button click for the GridView will not go to Page2.aspx?

(I have Googled this question, and the answers that others received did not work for my program).

Some of the code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("GoToPageTwo"))
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
            Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx");
        }
    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx");
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: When are you attaching the event handler? Can you also provide a simplified version of your .aspx page?

Comment: Can you verify in the VS debugger that the int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); statement is executed?  Put a breakpoint there.

Comment: I added a breakpoint at that line, and it was never executed. The GridView1_RowCommand function was was never executed either, and I finally figured out why. I didn't assign GridView1_RowCommand to onrowcommand. Once I did, it worked. Thanks for the help and suggestions.